# Is it a must to wear abaya and hijab outside the house?

Tags: hijab, clothing

Is it a must to wear abaya and hijab outside the house or can I wear modest clothes like long full sleeve shirt with jean pants or my traditional clothes which are a long shirt with trousers?

Please tell me if this is permissible by Islam or will I be punished?

Answer (score 3):

What you wear outside the house is irrelevant as long as it is according to the rules of shari'a (which means she should try to hide all of her body except with hands and face - this is the view on which there is consensus, some scholars may allow he to show her feet while others may ask her to hide her face too, but those are matters of fiqh or scholarly disputes).

Also you should know that woman might even need to wear hijab inside the house if there are foreign visitors. As verse ([24:31](http://legacy.quran.com/24/31)) is a general order and not specific for covering outside the house.

Note that the so called hijab verses seem explicitly indicating that this apply for the case of them going outside the house:

> O Prophet, tell your wives and your daughters and the women of the believers to bring down over themselves [part] of their outer garments. That is more suitable that they will be known and not be abused. And ever is Allah Forgiving and Merciful. ([33:59](http://legacy.quran.com/33/59))

For details read my answer on [Did women in Arabian peninsula have "Hijab" before Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7830/did-women-in-arabian-peninsula-have-hijab-before-islam/)

This verse seems to be have a direct relation to ([33:33](http://legacy.quran.com/33/33)) showing that it is more preferable to stay at home. So covering outside the house is therefore more emphasized by (33:59).

Answer (score -1):

> And say to the believing women that they should lower their gaze and guard their modesty; **that they should not display their beauty and ornaments except what (must ordinarily) appear thereof; that they should draw their *veils* over their bosoms and not display their beauty** except to their husbands, their fathers, their husband's fathers, their sons, their husbands' sons, their brothers or their brothers' sons, or their sisters' sons, or their women, or the slaves whom their right hands possess, or male servants free of physical needs, or small children who have no sense of the shame of sex; and that they should not strike their feet in order to draw attention to their hidden ornaments. And O ye Believers! turn ye all together towards Allah, that ye may attain Bliss.
>
> وَقُل لِّلْمُؤْمِنَاتِ يَغْضُضْنَ مِنْ أَبْصَارِهِنَّ وَيَحْفَظْنَ فُرُوجَهُنَّ وَلَا يُبْدِينَ زِينَتَهُنَّ إِلَّا مَا ظَهَرَ مِنْهَا ۖ وَلْيَضْرِبْنَ بِخُمُرِهِنَّ عَلَىٰ جُيُوبِهِنَّ ۖ وَلَا يُبْدِينَ زِينَتَهُنَّ إِلَّا لِبُعُولَتِهِنَّ أَوْ آبَائِهِنَّ أَوْ آبَاءِ بُعُولَتِهِنَّ أَوْ أَبْنَائِهِنَّ أَوْ أَبْنَاءِ بُعُولَتِهِنَّ أَوْ إِخْوَانِهِنَّ أَوْ بَنِي إِخْوَانِهِنَّ أَوْ بَنِي أَخَوَاتِهِنَّ أَوْ نِسَائِهِنَّ أَوْ مَا مَلَكَتْ أَيْمَانُهُنَّ أَوِ التَّابِعِينَ غَيْرِ أُولِي الْإِرْبَةِ مِنَ الرِّجَالِ أَوِ الطِّفْلِ الَّذِينَ لَمْ يَظْهَرُوا عَلَىٰ عَوْرَاتِ النِّسَاءِ ۖ وَلَا يَضْرِبْنَ بِأَرْجُلِهِنَّ لِيُعْلَمَ مَا يُخْفِينَ مِن زِينَتِهِنَّ ۚ وَتُوبُوا إِلَى اللَّهِ جَمِيعًا أَيُّهَ الْمُؤْمِنُونَ لَعَلَّكُمْ تُفْلِحُونَ
>
> 24:31

Comment: While the verse you quoted answers the question, adding a tafsir and some related comments from scholars will make the answer more understandable to the wide range of visitors to the site.

Comment: Evidences don't speak for themselves!

Comment: @Medi1Saif . Sometimes they do.

Comment: @TheZ we have a meta post on that https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/do-evidences-speak-for-themselves

Comment: In either case, I don't even feel this answers the question: *Is it a must to wear abaya and hijab outside the house?*  The ayah does not mention "abaya" nor "hijab" nor "outside the house".